# How to correctly requests.put in Python 3.7

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, datadog

I'm trying to communicate with datadog's api using the PUT method but failing with a "400" response. I've looked into the documentation and I'm confident my headers are set up correctly and access keys have been specified. Below is the function I'm working with:

```
def editMonitor(monitor_Data):

api_url = 'https://api.datadoghq.com/api/v1/monitor/' + str(monitor_Data['id'])

response = requests.put(api_url, monitor_Data, headers=headers)

print(response)

if response.status_code == 200:
    return json.loads(response.content.decode('utf-8'))
else:
    return None
```

Below is what the header is made of:

```
headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json',
           'DD-API-KEY': '**********************',
           'DD-APPLICATION-KEY': '***********************'
           }
```

Other articles I've seen so far don't seem to answer my question.

Comment: The indentation is wrong.

Comment: [@mkrieger1](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4621513/mkrieger1) even though the indentation is wrong, he stated that the problem is with the actual request as he gets a 400 status code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you take a look at the [`API documentation`](https://docs.datadoghq.com/api/v1/monitors/), you will notice it requires you to send required data into the body of the requests.

Here is an example on how to send data into the body using the requests module:

```
data = {
    "message": yourMessageInfo,
    "name": yourNameInfo,
    "object": yourObjectInfo,
    "priority": yourPriorityInfo,
    "query": yourQueryInfo,
    "tags": yourTagsInfo,
    "type": yourTypeInfo
}

response = requests.put(api_url, headers=headers, json=data)
```

You will of course need to fill in all the information.

Another example straight from the documentation:

```
data = {
  "message": "string",
  "name": "string",
  "options": {
    "enable_logs_sample": false,
    "escalation_message": "string",
    "evaluation_delay": "integer",
    "include_tags": false,
    "locked": false,
    "min_failure_duration": "integer",
    "min_location_failed": "integer",
    "new_host_delay": "integer",
    "no_data_timeframe": "integer",
    "notify_audit": false,
    "notify_no_data": false,
    "renotify_interval": "integer",
    "require_full_window": false,
    "restricted_roles": [],
    "silenced": {
      "<any-key>": "integer"
    },
    "synthetics_check_id": "string",
    "threshold_windows": {
      "recovery_window": "string",
      "trigger_window": "string"
    },
    "thresholds": {
      "critical": "number",
      "critical_recovery": "number",
      "ok": "number",
      "unknown": "number",
      "warning": "number",
      "warning_recovery": "number"
    },
    "timeout_h": "integer"
  },
  "priority": "integer",
  "query": "string",
  "tags": [],
  "type": "string"
}

response = requests.put(api_url, headers=headers, json=data)
```

More information in the [`API documentation`](https://docs.datadoghq.com/api/v1/monitors/) and the picture below:

[image: required headers image]

Comment: Hi thanks so, I am actually passing in all the necessary information needed through `monitor_Data` whose contents are from a JSON file that I'm reading in. I've set `data=monitor_Data` as well which still didn't work

Comment: You could also try `json=monitor_Data` and make sure `monitor_Data` has all the required fields filled in. Also set the `Content-Type` header to `application/json`

Comment: Thank you! your comment on `json=monitor_Data` solved my problem